# Jquery toggle separately

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to use Toggle my contents under separate list items.
But what s the best method to implement this in a generic way.
I dont want to give each content a separate class or id

http://jsfiddle.net/kKDWR/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery selector [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/). Try this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kKDWR/8/

Or you can use `.find()`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kKDWR/13/    
how can i disable the TOGGLE function on "a"(anchor) tag. I do not want to toggle when comments are clicked in my list

Comment: I want to remove Toggle functionality from "comments" DIV

Comment: take a look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/kKDWR/16/ I have moved the class to the anchor

Comment: You are faster than me :) i just found another answer but you were quicker      `code`$('.comments').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});`code`

Answer (score 0):

You make use of jQuery ... and you implement your feature in a jquery way. There's nothing wrong with it.

I'd only recommend to have a parent element (propably your current `<UL>`) with an ID (for example `<ul id="forum_entries>"`).
So you can address the items as `$(".tog", "#forum_entries")`. This can be much faster than simply addressing by classname, if your document becomes large.

Comment: OP was already using jQuery, and this does not answer their question

Comment: nevertheless it's worth thinking about generic on a classname base versus fast. It should have been a comment instead of an "answer".